# The condition is TRUE even though it should be FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got this condition:

```
if (((s.Id == r.Reserved.Id && (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)) && (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2)) || (!r.Reserved.IsReserved)){}
```

The first part of the condition is `s.Id == r.Reserved.Id` which means it should only be `true` if the Ids are the same. However the condition is `true` even if s.Id = 4 and r.Reserved.Id = 7 for example. Is there any problem with the bracelets? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Maybe break it up into variables so it’s not all one unreadable line.

Comment: The final `|| (!r.Reserved.IsReserved)` ignores the id

Comment: I think it's true, because !r.Reserved.IsReserved is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your expression.

```
(
    (
        s.Id == r.Reserved.Id &&
        (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)
    ) &&
    (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2)
) ||
    (!r.Reserved.IsReserved)
```

As you can see when it’s not all jammed into a line, the condition will also be true when `!r.Reserved.IsReserved` is true.

Now, it features a couple of confusing parentheses, so let’s take those out:

```
(
    s.Id == r.Reserved.Id &&
    (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2) &&
    (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2)
) || !r.Reserved.IsReserved
```

and reorganize to avoid repeating the `datumod2` check:

```
!r.Reserved.IsReserved ||
    s.Id == r.Reserved.Id &&
    (datumod2 == datumted2 ||
        r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now && r.DateTo > DateTime.Now)
```

and maybe make this kind of extension (syntax might be wrong but you get the idea):

```
public static bool IsInside<T : IComparable<T>>(this T x, T lower, T upper) {
    return lower < x && x < upper;
}
```

for:

```
!r.Reserved.IsReserved ||
    s.Id == r.Reserved.Id &&
    (datumod2 == datumted2 || DateTime.Now.IsInside(r.DateFrom, r.DateTo))
```

It’s hard to tell at this point without context, but maybe you’ll want to make a function:

```
private static bool SatisfiesCondition(Foo r, Bar s, Baz datumod2, Baz datumted2) {
    if (!r.Reserved.IsReserved)
        return true;

    if (s.Id != r.Reserved.Id)
        return false;

    if (datumod2 == datumted2)
        return true;

    return DateTime.Now.IsInside(r.DateFrom, r.DateTo);
}
```

rearrange conditions and pick names for maximum comprehensibility, and voilà:

```
if (SatisfiesCondition(r, s, datumod2, datumted2)) {
    ⋮
}
```

which has the added bonus of spelling out exactly which values affect the condition.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** -
`!r.Reserved.IsReserved` is True

---

Let's take apart your IF statement in order to understand the issue:

```
if (
    ( 
    // Condition One
        (s.Id == r.Reserved.Id && 
            (r.DateFrom < DateTime.Now || datumod2 == datumted2)
        ) && 
        (r.DateTo > DateTime.Now || datumdo2 == datumted2)
    // End Of Condition One
    ) || 
    (!r.Reserved.IsReserved) // Condition Two
)
```

Because the use of `OR` operator (`||`) your if statement would return True if either of the Conditdions (One or Two) are True. That's say, if you are sure that Condition One should be False and you still getting True, it means that your Condition Two is True -- i.e !r.Reserved.IsReserved is True